# When populating a table using 2D array in Java, there's an error, what is wrong with this code?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm starting my first steps with 2D arrays in Java. I require some help on a practical example. The below code should store students and their results for the 3 different courses in a table but the code throws an error. The error is caused by the line `int studentResults[x][y] = sc.nextInt();` Any ideas? Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

class CalcAverage 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("how many students?: ");
        int nbrOfStudents = sc.nextInt();

        int[][] studentResults ;

        studentResults = new int[nbrOfStudents][3] ;

        for (int x = 0 ; x < nbrOfStudents  ; x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Student " + (x + 1) + " : ");

            for (int y =0 ; y < 3 ; y++)
            {
                System.out.println("enter result course " + (y + 1) + " : ");
                int studentResults[x][y] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

    }// end main
}//end class
```

Comment: Please post the error message next time.. it contains everything you and anyone else would need to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just say `studentResults[x][y] = sc.nextInt();` with no `int` in front of it.

You only put the type in front of a variable name when you are first declaring it.